# Using PO / Check moneyorder "checkmo" for 0 dollar orders

Tags: payment-methods

We use the Check Money order payment method as "invoice" payment.
We also want to use this payment method for $0 orders.

but now when we select it we get "The requested Payment Method is not available."

Does anyone know a workaround. i've searched a lot but turned up with nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

The code that handles this is in `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php` in the `getMethods()` method.

Look for this part of the method:

`foreach ($methods as $key => $method) {
  if ($this->_canUseMethod($method)
        && ($total != 0
        || $method->getCode() == 'free'
        || ($quote->hasRecurringItems() 
            && $method->canManageRecurringProfiles()))) {
                    $this->_assignMethod($method);
  } else {
                    unset($methods[$key]);
  }
 }`

Look at the if statement. You can update that logic. The easiest (and sloppiest) thing you could do is change part of that if line to something like:

BEFORE: `|| $method->getCode() == 'free'`
AFTER: `|| ($method->getCode() == 'free' || $method->getCode() == 'checkmo')`

I'm not sure of your skill level. This way will work and it's the simplest, but you will lose this change if/when you upgrade Magento. It is bad practice to directly update the Magento core code.

See this link for how to properly override this method (it takes more steps): [Magento System Overrides and Upgradability](http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override)

Comment: Thank u Joa, but i tried it, but its not working :( Still getting "The requested payment method is not available"

Comment: In addition to this answer, do you have a Minimum Order Total set in System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Check/Money Order?